# how do I give the client access to remoteapp but prevent ts login?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services, remoteapp

I am running windows 2008 and have published an app with remoteapp in terminal services. That works great.

My question is, can I prevent the user from logging in to the server with rdp while still allowing them to access the remoteapp?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can. A RemoteApp is nothing more than a TS/RDS session that shows only the RemoteApp window(s). Behind the scenes the user will have a TS/RDS session on the server.

Comment: that just means I'll have to lock it down more to where they cannot do anything :(  k ty for the answer. Post a reply and I'll upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

In Local Policy , add username to "Local Policies > User Right Assignment > Deny log on through Terminal Services"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758613(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Um... this prevents both rdp and remoteapp from logging in, which defeats the purpose of my question.